# Can't get recurring GCal event to show up in FullCalendar with rrule

Tags: fullcalendar, rrule

I'm making calls to the Google Calendar API to retrieve event data. I want to display the events in a FullCalendar in my app. While normal events show up, I'm now working on getting recurring events to show up with all their instances.

Per the [FullCalendar documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/rrule-plugin), I'm using the rrule plugin. I have an event with data like this:

```
{
    "id": "6cvikr7n7g7ctler24dr1lgkjf",
    "title": "Test recurring event",
    "backgroundColor": "#9fe1e7",
    "borderColor": "#9fe1e7",
    "rrule": {
        "freq": "daily",
        "dtstart": "2022-09-14T15:00:00.000Z",
        "interval": 1,
        "until": "2022-12-31"
    },
    "duration": "00:30"
}
```

But this is not showing up in the FullCalendar. It ought to be an event that happens every day, starting 9/14/22, at 11am ET = 3pm UTC.

Am I missing something about how rrule and FullCalendar work?

Bonus: are there any tools that help translate a Google Calendar event's recurrence rules to a working rrule configuration?

Comment: Your event shows up fine - demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/eYEJOPp

Comment: As for translation tools, I don't know of any specifically, and recommendations for such are off-topic. Although, since fullCalendar has its own [module for reading Google Calendar events directly](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/google-calendar) I'm assuming there must be something in its source code which can understand a Google calendar recurring event and be able to re-display it in fullCalendar correctly. So if you don't want to use fullCalendar's functionality directly, you could always have a look at the code and see how they do it.

Comment: Thanks ADyson for both tips. It ended up being a dumb mistake on my part - see my answer below - but your codepen helped me realize it was probably a dumb mistake :) Though truth be told, not sure how your codepen works without declaring this plugin?

Comment: And great tip on looking into the FullCalendar integration code!

Comment: No worries. Regarding `not sure how your codepen works without declaring this plugin`...it's there in the list of external scripts if you look in the settings. When you use fullcalendar with script tags (which adding the script to the codepen settings is functionally equivalent to) you don't have to declare any plugins at all - that's only necessary when you use the ES6 build system method to initialise the calendar. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/initialize-globals and https://fullcalendar.io/docs/initialize-es6

Answer (score 1):

Dumb mistake on my part - I forgot to include rrulePlugin in the config for FullCalendar, i.e.:

```
<FullCalendar
...
    plugins={[ timeGridPlugin, rrulePlugin ]}
...
```